# Php count rows and division into a group

Tags: php, laravel

Users create accounts and they are assigned to a group, group limit is set in advance, let's assume 5.

Example: First 5 users has been saved to group_id = 1. Than how to make the 6th user have been saved to the 2nd group?

```
UserGroups::insert([
    'user_id' => $user,
    'game_id' => $gameId,
    'group_id' => 1
]);
```

How to make this dynamic for some groups, like group_id = 3..4..5..6 etc ?

Example code:

```
$groupSize = 2;
$allUserGroups = 4;

if($groupSize < $allUserGroups) {
UserGroups::insert([
    'user_id' => $user,
    'game_id' => $gameId,
    'group_id' => 1
]);
} else {
    UserGroups::insert([
        'user_id' => $user,
        'game_id' => $gameId,
        'group_id' => 2
    ]);
}
```

This is only work with two groups - how to make this dynamic ?

Thanks guys!

Comment: see my answer i have done that

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arrayUsers=['user1','user2','user3','user4','user5',
    'user6','user7','user8','user9','user10',
    'user11','user12','user13','user14','user15'];


$group_id=1;

echo'<pre>';
$groupedUser=array_chunk($arrayUsers, 5);

foreach($groupedUser as $data ){
    $newArray[$group_id]=$data ;
    $group_id++;
}

print_r($newArray);
```

So let's assume that your users are in the array i created. array_chunk will split them in groups of the number you want. As you said in your question i splitted them in groups of 5. Then to create dynamic groups i just used a counter which i increment by one everytime my array field was full (5 records). In the output you will get a multidimensional array with keys the group_id and values the users.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => user1
            [1] => user2
            [2] => user3
            [3] => user4
            [4] => user5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => user6
            [1] => user7
            [2] => user8
            [3] => user9
            [4] => user10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => user11
            [1] => user12
            [2] => user13
            [3] => user14
            [4] => user15
        )

)
```

Comment: Yes i know but its not array. The user registers individually and writes to the database. It is not possible to send several users in the form of an array

Comment: Then you will have to query the db (SELECT) , return all the users as an array and use array_chunk there.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem your are looking for this solution :-

```
$getgroups = UserGroups::select('group_id',DB::raw('count(group_id) as count'))->groupby('group_id')->get();
    $getgroups = json_decode(json_encode($getgroups),true);
    if(!empty($getgroups)){
        end($getgroups); 
        $key = key($getgroups);
        $group = $getgroups[$key];
        if($group['count'] <5){
            UserGroups::insert([
                'user_id' => $user,
                'game_id' => $gameId,
                'group_id' => $group['group_id']
            ]);
        }else{
            $groupvalue = $group['group_id'] +1;
            UserGroups::insert([
                'user_id' => $user,
                'game_id' => $gameId,
                'group_id' => $groupvalue
            ]);
        }
    }else{
        UserGroups::insert([
                'user_id' => $user,
                'game_id' => $gameId,
                'group_id' => 1
            ]);
    }
    echo "saved"; die;
```

I have tested its working perfectly. Good luck for your project :)